# Bootstrap + Rails,Items stacking on one single column instead of spreading across row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a rails tutorial , and my items are stacking on one single column instead of spreading across the row

```
    <div class ="row">
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= image_tag listing.image.url(:thumb)%><br>
    <%= listing.name %><br>
    <%= listing.description %><br>
    <%= listing.price %><br>
    <%= link_to 'Show', listing, class: "btn btn-link" %><br>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing), class: "btn btn-link" %><br>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', listing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-link" %>
  <div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: If this is the exact code you're trying to test then you have a typo. The closing tag for `<div class="col-md-3">` is written as `<div>` but should be `</div>`

Comment: To confirm, are they stacked in one column even when you’re browser is expanded / full screen?

Answer (score 0):

It will, you have to create a new row after column reaches to 12. As per your code it will take 4 rounds. Quick way to do this would be using a counter.

Comment: Not necessarily, they should stack properly without the need to define a new row: https://codepen.io/glebez/pen/EoPwQx